# Is there a way to get a users Hardware-ID in C#?

Tags: c#, registry, regedit, hardware-id, hwid

Im trying to get the hwid of a user using csharp for a program kind of like stuff like PredatorSense which shows ur cpu speed and other stuff, ive tried using the Registry.GetValue method from Microsoft.Win32 yet idk how to use it, Heres my code. `string hwid = Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\IDConfigDB\Hardware Profiles\0001", "REG_SZ", null).ToString();`

Answer (score 1):

i figured it out, heres my updated code. `string hwid = Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\IDConfigDB\Hardware Profiles\0001", "HwProfileGuid", null).ToString();`